# Как встроить лист Excel в приложение WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

Я бы хотел использовать "мощь" Excel в моём приложении на WPF, и чтоб встроенный лист экселя брал значения из моей программы и обрабатывал их.
Возможен ли такой вариант? Только чтоб Excel был внутри программы, а не ещё 1 внешний файл, куда надо было бы переносить данные и потом там обрабатывать...

Comment: http://help.syncfusion.com/resources/Ug_101/User%20Interface/WPF/Grid
http://help.syncfusion.com/resources/Ug_101/User%20Interface/WPF/Spreadsheet
кое что нашёл

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону класса `AxHost`

Comment: Спасибо, а ктонибудь может привести пример, как это сделать?